# What is google Cloud CLI command to retrieve current date populated files presented in the bucket ? without specifying date manually

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bucket

What is google Cloud CLI command to retrieve current dated files presented in the Google Storage bucket ? without specifying date manually. Do we have any sysdate or createdate kind of command ?

Answer (score 0):

With this CLI Command, you can get files with the current date from the bucket you specify:

```
gsutil ls -l gs://[your-bucket-name]/ | sort -r -k 2
```

See sample output below:
[image]